# How to run parallel make with debuild?

Tags: compiling, deb, packaging, make, debuild

I am trying to make a package of a piece of software that I've (co-) written. I'm using

```
debuild -i -us -uc -b
```

And in principle that works fine. In order to shorten compilation time I'd like to debuild to run make in parallel (like I normally do by running `make -j4`, for example).
I've found a few locations on the web that suggest the following:

```
debuild -eDEB_BUILD_OPTIONS="parallel=4" -us -uc -b
debuild -j4 -us -uc -b
```

Another site suggested to add some code to the `debian/rules` file that basically sets

```
MAKEFLAGS += -j4
```

However, none of these seems to work. Have I missed something? or should I change something in the autoconf/automake settings of the source?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It has to be enabled in debian/rules. If the package uses dh, there is a line like this in debian/rules:

```
dh $@
```

Change that to

```
dh $@ --parallel
```

Then your commands will work, at least DEB_BUILD_OPTIONS="parallel=4"

Comment: Just remember to export `DEB_BUILD_OPTIONS` to make all the tools happy.

Comment: The `--parallel` option is no longer needed, just set the environment variable.

Answer (score 11):

I recommend using the `DEB_BUILD_OPTIONS` environment variable, as described in [section 4.9.1](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-source.html#debian-rules-and-deb-build-options) of the Debian Policy Manual.

```
DEB_BUILD_OPTIONS='parallel=4' debuild -i -us -uc -b
```

Comment: BTW, this env variable doesn't work for `dpkg-buildpackage` command. It has its own option `-j=4` which works. But equal sign `=` is important.

Answer (score 10):

With debhelper 10, you no longer need to supply the `--parallel` option in `debian/rules`; it now runs parallel builds by default.  See the [release notes](https://nthykier.wordpress.com/2016/09/11/debhelper-10-is-now-available/)

The answer, is therefore, just to set the contents of `debian/compat` to `10` and to update the `debhelper` version to `>=10` in `debian/control`.

Answer (score 0):

To sum-up all the above, that worked for me:

```
export DEB_BUILD_OPTIONS='parallel=16'
fakeroot debian/rules binary
```