# How can I make debhelper honor parallel=n?

Tags: compiling, deb, packaging, debuild

I'm trying to make a Debian package for a cmake project that, in single-threaded mode, takes 3 hours to compile. I'm trying to get a parallel build, but failing.

I've tried setting [`parallel=4`](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-source.html#debian-rules-and-deb-build-options) in my `control` file like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/make -f
export DEB_BUILD_OPTIONS="parallel=4"

%:
    dh $@ --parallel
```

Based on the accepted answer on [this previous question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/337093/how-to-run-parallel-make-with-debuild), but I get the following warning:

```
dh: warning: invalid flag in DEB_BUILD_OPTIONS: "parallel=4"
```

And debhelper still invokes `make -j1`.

I've tried variations on the theme based on other suggestions/comments I've found online, `DEB_BUILD_OPTIONS="-j=4"`, `DEB_BUILD_OPTIONS="-j4"` etc to no effect. I've tried setting `debian/compat` to `10`. Always the result is `invalid flag`. How can I make debhelper honor this setting?

I'm doing the build in an Ubuntu Focal x86_64 docker container, and my version of `debhelper` is `12.10ubuntu1`.

Comment: `-j` is a make option. DEB_BUILD_OPTIONS [allow `parallel=n`](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-source.html#s-debianrules-options)

Comment: I figured `-j` was wrong, but I tried it because `parallel=4` gives the error in the question.

Comment: probably you need to detect number of CPUs with `-j'nproc'` or `-j'getconf NPROCESSORS_ONLN'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, I had the Makefile syntax wrong.

The error message I was seeing came from [a regular expression in `dpkg` itself](https://salsa.debian.org/dpkg-team/dpkg/-/blob/1.19.7/scripts/Dpkg/BuildOptions.pm#L95) excerpted here:

```perl
         unless (/^([a-z][a-z0-9_-]*)(?:=(\S*))?$/) {
             warning(g_('invalid flag in %s: %s'), $source, $_);
             next;
         }
```

I re-read that regular expression a million times before I realized that the second `%s` in the warning does not have quotes around it, which means in the error message:

```
dh: warning: invalid flag in DEB_BUILD_OPTIONS: "parallel=4"
```

The quotes around `"parallel=4"` are coming *from the environment variable itself* not from the format string.

The fix, is to change

```
export DEB_BUILD_OPTIONS="parallel=4"
```

to

```
export DEB_BUILD_OPTIONS = parallel=4
```

because when setting the environment variable, `make` is preserving the quotes in the first version. When make is doing the string interpolation, it makes no practical difference because the quotes get eaten by the shell, but when a subprocess reads the value from an environment, the `"` characters are preserved.

```
#!/usr/bin/make -f
export WITH_QUOTES="parallel=3"
export WITHOUT_QUOTES = parallel=3

all:
    bash -c 'printf "WITH_QUOTES=%q\n" "$$WITH_QUOTES"'
    bash -c 'printf "WITHOUT_QUOTES=%q\n" "$$WITHOUT_QUOTES"'
```

```
bash -c 'printf "WITH_QUOTES=%q\n" "$WITH_QUOTES"'
WITH_QUOTES=\"parallel=3\"
bash -c 'printf "WITHOUT_QUOTES=%q\n" "$WITHOUT_QUOTES"'
WITHOUT_QUOTES=parallel=3
```

Having the actual value of the environment variable be `"parallel=4"` not `parallel=4` both triggered the warning, and broke [this regular expression that `dh` uses to parse it](https://salsa.debian.org/debian/debhelper/-/blob/debian/12.10/lib/Debian/Debhelper/Dh_Lib.pm#L2497) (note leading ^):

```perl
        if ($opt =~ /^parallel=(-?\d+)$/ && $wanted eq 'parallel') {
            return $1;
        }
```

Comment: Good catch. :) I'm not so advanced I didn't notice that. Anyway, GNU Make also put something in documentation (No quotes to append text). See https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Appending

Comment: @user.dz It's kind-of a shame your earlier answer got deleted, though. Somebody else searching for this class of problem is probably more likely to make the mistake you thought I'd made.

Comment: I removed it because, it does reference an obsolete doc.  As you mentioned,  debhelper already handles related variable mapping in current version.

Comment: Still, if your `rules` file defines any of the `override_dh_*` rules, you'll have to parse `DEB_BUILD_OPTIONS` looking for `parallel=` yourself. The magic only applies to tasks `dh` does for you.

Answer (score 2):

> **Note:**
> OP solved the issue, it is documented in [his own answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1416410/26246). I left this answer which give a hint for the ones using custom build steps (`override_dh_*`). As they have to map the variable.

Documentation you referenced [debian/rules and DEB_BUILD_OPTIONS](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-source.html#debian-rules-and-deb-build-options), mentions that it should be mapped/implemented in the lower level too.

> The following makefile snippet is an example of how one may implement
> the build options; you will probably have to massage this example in
> order to make it work for your package.
>
> ```
> ...
> ifneq (,$(filter parallel=%,$(DEB_BUILD_OPTIONS)))
>     NUMJOBS = $(patsubst parallel=%,%,$(filter parallel=%,$(DEB_BUILD_OPTIONS)))
>     MAKEFLAGS += -j$(NUMJOBS)
> endif
> ...
> ```

While the doc gives a `make` example, in this case an equivalent one should be used for `cmake`. It will not be hard finding a template from source of another package or from launchpad directly.

This is an example from `cmake` package itself, mapping the flag inside `debian/rules` directly (so still Makefile syntax):

```
ifneq (,$(filter parallel=%,$(DEB_BUILD_OPTIONS)))
    NUMJOBS = $(patsubst parallel=%,%,$(filter parallel=%,$(DEB_BUILD_OPTIONS)))
    BOOTSTRAP_FLAGS += --parallel=$(NUMJOBS)
endif

override_dh_auto_configure: $(BUILD_FLAGS_FILE)
        rm -rf Build && mkdir -p Build
        cd Build && ../bootstrap $(BOOTSTRAP_FLAGS)
```

Source: Any native source archive `cmake*.tar.xz` from [Daily build of upstream cmake - Launchpad project](https://launchpad.net/%7Eubuntu-support-team/+archive/ubuntu/cmake/+packages)

Comment: My entire rules file is a call to `dh $@` which means it's already mapped/implemented in the lower level by debhelper itself. The [`-j' flag debhelper passes to make`](https://salsa.debian.org/debian/debhelper/-/blob/main/lib/Debian/Debhelper/Buildsystem/cmake.pm#L175) comes from [reading `$DEB_BUILD_OPTIONS`](https://salsa.debian.org/debian/debhelper/-/blob/main/lib/Debian/Debhelper/Dh_Lib.pm#L2615)